# UITableViewController with UISearchDisplayController multiple selection sync

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way of keeping row selection in sync between a `UITableViewController` and a `UISearchDisplayController`.

When a row is selected in the `UITableViewController` I want the same row to appear as selected when the `UISearchDisplayController` is `active`, and vice versa.

Both `tableView` objects have `allowsMultipleSelection` set to `YES`.

Answer (score 2):

The basis of this technique was gleaned from Erica Sadun's very helpful book "The Core iOS 6 Developer's Cookbook" fourth edition, published by Addison Wesley. I have developed many solutions from the ideas and code presented in Erica's book.

---

**Notes**

- This is not elegant but it does work.
- This solution is for a target running iOS 7 and below. `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8 in favour of `UISearchController`.
- To attempt to keep the answer as short as possible, this solution leaves out chunks of code necessary to properly prepare both `self.tableView` and `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` table views.
- This solution assumes use of functioning Core Data Stack and `NSFetchedResultsController`.

---

Essentially we use an `NSMutableDictionary` to maintain a record of selected cell/s that is used by both `self.tableView` and `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`.

This technique can be used for table views and controllers that are intended to register and track one or more selected cells.

I may miss a few steps as it has been a while since I implemented this solution, so let me know and I will check it.

### Step One

Prepare a set of public properties, including...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectID *managedObjectID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayObjects;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^blockSelectManagedObjectID)(NSManagedObjectID *objectID);
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^blockSelectManagedObjects)(NSArray *objects);
```

The properties `managedObjectID` and `arrayObjects` are set using a `prepareForSegue` method contained within the parent TVC. Only one or the other is set, depending on whether you are passing one `NSManagedObjectID` (single selection), or an `NSArray` of multiple `NSManagedObject`s (multiple selections).

The property `isArray` could be removed, but I include it for my ease of coding and code readability. It is also set in the same `prepareForSegue` method within the parent TVC mentioned above.

The blocks are defined in the parent TVC and update data in the parent TVC when exiting this TVC.

To summarise, apart from `searchResults`, these public properties are set by the parent TVC.

### Step Two

Prepare a set of private properties, including...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryTableRowCheckedState; //our primary dictionary!
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayObjectsSelected;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPathSelected;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexPathObjectFromArray;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectID *cellObjectID;
```

### Step Three

Set your private properties in the TVC lifecycle method `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self setDictionaryTableRowCheckedState:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
    [self setArrayObjectsSelected:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.arrayObjects]];

    [self setIndexPathSelected:nil];
    [self setIndexPathObjectFromArray:nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    //<<_YOUR_OTHER_CODE_>>
}
```

### Step Four

Prepare to populate your `UITableViewCell`s using the TVC data source method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as follows...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //<<_YOUR_OTHER_CODE_>>
    //<<including...>>

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        rowEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        rowEntity = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [self setCellObjectID:[rowEntity objectID]];

    //<<_YOUR_OTHER_CODE_>>

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    NSIndexPath *indexPathLastManagedObject = nil;

    //  If there exists 'checked' value/s, manage row checked state
    if (self.managedObjectID || self.arrayObjects.count) {
        BOOL isChecked = NO;
        if (!self.isArray) {
            if (self.cellObjectID == self.managedObjectID) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                isChecked = YES;
                self.indexPathSelected = indexPath;
                NSManagedObject *localManagedObject = nil;
                if (tableView == self.tableView) {
                    localManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                } else {
                    localManagedObject = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                }
                indexPathLastManagedObject = indexPath;
                self.managedObjectID = localManagedObject.objectID;
            }

        } else if (self.isArray) {
            if (self.arrayObjectsSelected.count) {
                for (NSManagedObject *localManagedObject in self.arrayObjectsSelected) {
                    if (self.cellObjectID == localManagedObject.objectID) {
                        isChecked = YES;
                        indexPathLastManagedObject = indexPath;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            self.dictionaryTableRowCheckedState[indexPath] = @(isChecked);
            cell.accessoryType = isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - has (possible undefined) E~R~R~O~R attempting to set UITableViewCellAccessory at indexPath: %@_", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), indexPath);
        }

    }
    return cell;
}
```

### Step Five

Of course we need a fairly chunky TVC delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to handle the selection and deselection of cells by the user.

Notice that I highlight the use of block callbacks in my code, although these have not been mentioned in detail - it is my method of choice to update data in the parent TVCs. If you'd like me to update the code to incorporate block callbacks let me know (just a lot of code here already).

Notice also that I pop the TVC when we are in single selection mode. If we are in multiple cell selection mode, the return to the parent TVC must obviously be manual.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!self.isArray) {
        if (self.indexPathSelected) {
            if ((indexPath.section == self.indexPathSelected.section)
                && (indexPath.row == self.indexPathSelected.row)) {
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                [self setIndexPathSelected:nil];
            } else {
                NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = self.indexPathSelected;
                UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
                [oldCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
                [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
                [self setIndexPathSelected:indexPath];
                NSManagedObject *localManagedObject = nil;
                if (tableView == self.tableView) {
                    localManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                } else {
                    localManagedObject = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                }
                NSManagedObjectID *localObjectID = localManagedObject.objectID;
                [self blockSelectManagedObjectID](localObjectID); //block callback to update parent TVC
            }
        } else {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
            [self setIndexPathSelected:indexPath];
            NSManagedObject *localManagedObject = nil;
            if (tableView == self.tableView) {
                localManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            } else {
                localManagedObject = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            NSManagedObjectID *localObjectID = localManagedObject.objectID;
            [self blockSelectManagedObjectID](localObjectID); //block callback to update parent TVC
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    } else if (self.isArray) {
        NSManagedObject *localManagedObject = nil;
        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            localManagedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        } else {
            localManagedObject = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        //  Toggle the cell checked state
        __block BOOL isChecked = !((NSNumber *)self.dictionaryTableRowCheckedState[indexPath]).boolValue;
        self.dictionaryTableRowCheckedState[indexPath] = @(isChecked);
        [cell setAccessoryType:isChecked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        if (isChecked) {
            [self.arrayObjectsSelected addObject:localManagedObject];
        } else {
            [self.arrayObjectsSelected removeObject:localManagedObject];
        }
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - has (possible undefined) E~R~R~O~R at indexPath: %@_", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), indexPath);
    }
}
```

### Step Six

This code in the TVC lifecycle method `viewWillDisappear` updates the data in the parent TVC when it is an `NSArray` of managed objects that is being returned, or in the case that a single managed object ID row is simply deselected and no other row is selected (in the case that the row was selected (check marked) on entering the table view / TVC).

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - values for:\n   indexPathSelected:        %@\n   indexPathObjectFromArray: %@\n\n", NSStringFromClass(self.class), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.indexPathSelected, self.indexPathObjectFromArray);

    if (self.passBackManagedObjects) {
        if (self.isArray) {
            //  Return an array of selected NSManagedObjects
            [self blockSelectManagedObjects](self.arrayObjectsSelected);
        } else if (self.indexPathSelected == nil) {
            //  Return nil where a previously selected (optional) entity is deactivated
            [self blockSelectManagedObjectID](nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you enjoy working through this little treat! Any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You use the same data source so that technically you do not sync.  Use a single set of objects to do the check.

Any `UITableView` subclass needs to call the `UITableViewDataSource` `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method when `reloadData`.  That's where you do something like

```
if (![selectionSet containsObject:object]) { 
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
}
else {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:NO];
}
```

It's best to override the `UITableViewCell` `setSelected:animated:` method too IMO so you can have more control over `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Good luck, hope this helps~