# Multiple Selection while searchController is filtering

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisearchcontroller, multipleselection

I have been searching and have only found this post here on my question. 
[How do I select multiple table rows from filtered results of a Searchbar and SearchDisplayController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641591/how-do-i-select-multiple-table-rows-from-filtered-results-of-a-searchbar-and-sea)

Essentially I need the same thing. I need to filter the table (Which I am already doing correctly) and then need to be able to select multiple rows from the filtered results.

For a more visualization.
After filtering the table like below:
[image]

How will I be able to select multiple lines like below WHILE I am filtering:
[image]

Is this possible?

Based on the link I provided to a similar question which is a very old question.

```
self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

Error: searchDisplayController was deprecated in iOS 8.0

For this code here:

```
self.searchController.searchResultsController.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

Error: value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'allowsMultipleSelection

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this once I set

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

along with

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```