# UISearchBar with multiple scope selection

Tags: ios, swift, filter, uisearchbar

I'm attempting to create a search bar with multiple filter scopes in Xcode, Swift 4.2, I have created the search bar with filters and it works as intended. However, I wish to expand the functionality so the user can select more than one filter's from the scope selection.

For example, selects "Unread" and "High Importance" and it will find all items where it meets BOTH of these criteria. I think I could easily get that logic down but I'm trying to find a way of setting the scope filters to be multi-select, I can't seem to find an option in Xcode.

Comment: You can do this by adding 2 default header in `UITableView`. When user tapped on `searchBar` then you have to display `UITableView` with that 2 filter and when user type any character hide that 2 filter and load Searched data based on user input.

Comment: @Denis my problem isn't displaying the correct data, it's selected two scope filters simultaneously. Xcode only allows me to select a single one at any given time

Comment: check this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641591/how-do-i-select-multiple-table-rows-from-filtered-results-of-a-searchbar-and-sea

Comment: you just in need to pass a bool value

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I'm not using UISearchController or the new UISearchController. I'm using UISearchBar which has filters built in the form of scopes. I'm trying to find out how to select multiple scopes on the UISearchBar

Comment: then you may check for any custom third party searcher. like below 
https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu